# Android/iPhone/Web app to send a picture directly to company server without saving it to the phone

Tags: android, web-apps, iphone-app

I'm trying to find a mobile application to take photos of sensitive documents which are then securely sent directly to my company's server (through SFTP or other means). However, the picture should **not be stored on the phone** before sending it, just like the online banking apps that take a picture of a check.

I've seen many options for making my own webpage to upload the picture, but none pre-made in a mobile app format.

Does an app like this exist? If not, what's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first from the technical point of view **i doubt this is possible**... every camera-app i know saves its pictures on the device or memory-card.
in your case you would have to look for a special camera-app saving pictures not localy but as said, i doubt this exists. this will also result in a "not working" camera-app with no/poor network connection or when the server itself is not available.

---

lets go further to find something like a **applicable solution**:...

- if it is really **sensitive data** you are dealing with, every medium it is stored on, **should be encrypted** (also think about the server). - even if the data is just cached for a short time; deleted data are not really deleted, especially on flash storages!
- then you can use pretty every good app to sync your data to your server. - the app will depend on what protocol you are using. *(FolderSync works with several servers/protocols, is capable of instant-sync and also auto-deletion of data after synchronization, if you are looking for that.)*
  pay attention that at least the transport is encrypted via SSL/TLS or SSH; the best will be a VPN to communicate with your server.